# How to execute a command for each of the sub folders?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I have the following structure:

```
parent_folder
     |______subfolder1
     |           |________sub_subfolder_1
     |           |________sub_subfolder_2
     |           |________sub_subfolder_3
     |          
     |______subfolder2
                 |________sub_subfolder_4
                 |________sub_subfolder_5
                 |________sub_subfolder_6
```

I need to be able to execute certain command on each of the `sub_subfolder_x`'s

For my example I just try to echo the folders names.

this is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
for /d %%x in (*) do (
cd %%x
for /d %%y in (*/%%x) do (
echo %%y
)
)
```

When I simply do

```
for /d %%x in (*) do (
echo %%x
)
```

it works and lists all the folders under the `parent_folder`. But my script that tries to cd to `(*/%%x)` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is `*/%%x`. It should be `%%x\*`. You don't need to `cd` into that folder (and if you do, better use `pushd`, so you can easily revert it with `popd`)

```
@echo off
for /d %%x in (*) do (
  for /d %%y in ("%%x\*") do (
    echo %%y
  )
)
```

Comment: Perfect. This works like the script I wrote but looks better. ty for the explanation as well

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that also works for me:

```bath
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0\parent_folder"

for /d %%x in (*) do (
     cd /d "%cd%\%%~x"
     for /d %%y in (*) do (    
         echo current sub folder is %%y
        )
    )
pause
```

I just did some trial and errors until I made it work. I wonder if it is problematic from some reason and will not work in some cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the names of the sub folders by using dir with some switches and store them in an array (It's a bit of a trick because batch does not actually support arrays).

After that you can loop through this array.
Then you change directory to each of the folders in the array and execute the piece of code you want to execute in each of the sub folders.

Here is an example of that:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM Retrieve Parent Folder
set parentfolder=%cd%

REM Retrieve Subfolders
set i=0
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad *') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set "folder!i!=%%F"
)

REM Loop Through Sub Folders
for /l %%N in (1 1 %i%) do (
cd %parentfolder%\!folder%%N!
echo do something
)
```

Comment: thanks, I also found a working way (look at my answer) - what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

```py
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

for /r /d %%i in (.) do pushd "%%~fi" && =;(
    %ComSpec% /v /r "echo\"!cd!"" & popd );=
```

---

Try using `for /R /D`, in one loop recursive in all subdirectories and run your command in each folder, being inside it:

```py
 for /r /d %%i in (.) do pushd "%%~fi" && %ComSpec% /v /r "[Your Command Here]" & popd
```

- ```py
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```py
  The option /D /r is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

---

**Obs.:** If your command needs to make use of some "dependent" file that is in the looped folder (`"%%~fi"`), a `pushd`, `command` & `popd` will help you to execute the command in each folder correctly

- Some further reading:
- **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**
- **[Pushd /?](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)**

  - **[Popd /?](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)**
- **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
- **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
- **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**
- **[DelayedExpansion | `%ComSpec% /v /r`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "curdir=%~dp0"
set "subdir=%curdir:~0,-1%\parent_folder"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%d in (`dir /b /s /a:d "%subdir%"`) do echo %%d
```